# Sending mail Through SMTP

Tags: c#, smtp

I'm sending mail through SMTP client. I have specified server address username and password.

```
var smtpClient= new SmtpClient(server,portNumber )
                                 {
                                     DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
                                     EnableSsl = false,
                                     Timeout = 10000
                                 };
smtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password, domain);
 var sender = new MailAddress(EmailAddess, "abc");
                var message = new MailMessage()
                {
                    IsBodyHtml = false,
                    Sender = sender,
                    From = sender,
                    Body = "Plain text test",
                    Subject = "Test Message, Please ignore"
                };
smtpClient.Send(message);
```

If the Servername and Port is Correct it does not validate credentials and sends the mail even if username and password is incorrect.
Do I have to add additional validation for Credentials?

Comment: That sounds like a problem with the SMTP server, not with the code.

Comment: If it weren't then this would be heaven for spammers :)

Comment: Sorry, but what was the question? Is the code giving you an error or is it a hypothetical question?

Comment: code is not giving any error. its just even if i give anything random for username and password it will still send the mail

Answer (score 1):

> if the Servername and Port is Correct it does not validate credentials
>   and sends the mail even if username and password is incorrect. Do I
>   have to add additional validation for Credentials?

Depends on the server. Espeically internal servers (i.e. not reachable via internet) will gladly relay emails from IP's without username and password. For example my companies internal email servers accept emails from certain IP ranges without asking for a username or password.

Also if the email goes TO a server it does normally not require authentication. This is generally only needed for relaying (i.e. when the server is supposed to send the email to another server).

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this.

```
 System.Net.Mail.MailMessage message = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
    message.To.Add(ToEmail);
    message.Subject = Subject;
    message.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(FromEmail);
    message.Body = Message;
    System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient smtpAddress = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("IP");
    smtpAddress.Send(message);
```

ToEmail = Who shall recieve the Email.
Subject = The subject of the email.
FromEmail = Who has send the Email. (Can be anything)
Message = The message.
IP = is the the SMTPCLIENT IP